# ActivClient add-on crashes Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions, smartcard

My work requires that I access to websites under the DoD umbrella using a CAC card, with ActivClient as the smartcard middleware. The security device is registered with the help of an add-on called "ActivClient Security Module."

When a website requiring CAC authentication is first visited, the native Firefox dialog pops up prompting for the password to unlock the smartcard. The problem occurs when, after a while, the ActivClient add-on dialog pops up instead of the native one, which abruptly causes the browser to crash as soon as a password is entered.

Comment: Stop using the extension that is crashing FireFox?

Comment: Did you read the question? I need the extension to use my smart card, or at least I thought I did. My intention was to uninstall the add-on and register the security module by hand before posting an answer here, which I've done, but the problem pop-up still comes up even with the add-on uninstalled.

Comment: I did and what I read is that FireFox has a native dialog, which suggests it can support the smartcard. This question would get answered in a more specific forum:

https://militarycac.com/activclient.htm

https://support.actividentity.com/Service/WebObjects/Service.woa/wa/knowledge

SuperUser may not be the best place for this question.

It looks to me like there is no Linux support for ActivClient.